# Increase a variable up to a maximum size

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a simple game that you put the number of enemies and you hit them or cure yourself. But, the player has a maximum amount of 500 of life. The cure uses `random.randint(10,14)`.

```
if player_sp >= 10:
    if player_vida < 500:
        cura = random.randint(10,14)
        player_vida += cura
        print("Foi adicionado %i de vida!"%cura)
        player_sp -= 10
```

This is the code to cure, but if you are curing the player the amount of life may pass 500. How can I cure the player without exceeding 500 in python? I tried making another `if else` using player_vida >= 500 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about replacing:

```
player_vida += cura
```

with:

```
player_vida = min(500, player_vida + cura)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `min()` function to cap the player's life at 500.

```
# ...
player_vida += cura
player_vida = min(500, player_vida)
```